# Android WebChromeClient doesnt play video but Chrome browser do in kitkat OS?

Tags: android, html, video, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I have the following webview settings to play the video which is embedded ina html using video tag(html 5).

```
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

This settings allow the video to be played in Lolipop and above versions of Android, however in Kitkat the video doesn't play and I am getting a black screen with video controls.

Please find the screenshots attached:
**Kitkat**:
<kbd>[image: Kitkat OS webview video player with blank screen]</kbd>
**Lolipop**:
<kbd>[image]</kbd>

even the player shown in webviews are different even though I use a Chromewebclient in my webview in kitkat.

Is there a way to play html5 video in Android webview of Kikat Os Android?

Comment: does the video play back in the browser natively? it may be encoded in a way that's not supported

Comment: @Offbeatmammal in some Kitkat device's Chrome browser it played fine and the browser player looks like one in the lolipop screenshot above. however in my app I am getting a different player as shown in kikat sceenshot above. That is why I am concerned.